# Storybook add custom text in the sidebar

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, storybook

I've faced the issue with the storybook library + ReactJS.
I need to display a custom text under the brand image in the storybook. Is there any option in the storybook library to achieve it?

Are we able to get a sidebar instance or pass custom renderer function somehow?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this question, Ihor Lavs. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MaximilianC. unfortunately no. I didn't find the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In my preview.js in .storybook file I accessed the label which is between the sidebar-header and combo box with the id 'downshift-1-label' with the following code:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const label = window.parent.document.querySelector('#downshift-1-label');
  if (label) {
    label.setAttribute(
      'style',
      'left: 5px; overflow: visible; position: relative; top: 5px; font-size: 14px;',
    );
  }
});
```

The style makes it appear properly right where you want it.

I added text with the `label.innerHTML = 'Test Text'`.

**Side note**: I am using version 6.5.16 of storybook, maybe this label isn't present in the new versions of the storybook.
Haven't tested it out but hopefully you can access the parent of this label with the same `window.parent.document.querySelector('.parentClassName');` method.